# emberjs Uncaught You cannot load data into the store when its associated model is in its current state

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm getting this error in emberjs 0.9.8.1

```
Uncaught You cannot load data into the store when its associated model is in its current state
```

I'm just trying to get my data like this

```
App.myController.get('content').get('someProperty');
```

and that error occurs. the data is already loaded into the content of the controller and I'm just trying to grab it. I'm using ember data and this is my model that's having the problem

```
App.MemberInfo = DS.Model.extend({
        primaryKey: 'level',
        levelCopy: DS.attr('string'),
        level: DS.attr('string'),
        contactInfo: DS.hasOne('App.ContactInfoModel', { embedded: true })
    });
```

I'm reloading the controller content using the App.store.find method (ember data). the error happens after doing find second time for the same model.
when the contactInfo attribute wasn't there. there was no problem. it happens when contactInfo is added.

Comment: Can you add a sample code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? If you don't know how to use jsfiddle, watch this [YouTube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrWkRHSK6A8)

Comment: my code involves doing ajax call to get data from the server, etc. i can't put that in jfiddle. thanks. i'm basically just trying to get the value like this App.myController.get('content').get('someProperty'); and that's throwing the error. sorry i can't provide more info.

Comment: i added more info that could help. thanks!

Comment: Not very familiar with Ember-Data, sorry.

Comment: Use the (Chrome or Firefox) console and copy the **stack trace** here

Answer (score 1):

Which version of ember-data are you using? The `hasOne` relation does not exist anymore since a very long time...

You should use `belongsTo` relation, on the owning side (the model which carries the id reference).

---

By the way, a little hint for a more idiomatic code:

```
App.myController.get('content').get('someProperty');
```

should be written:

```
App.myController.getPath('content.someProperty');
```

or with ember-edge

```
App.myController.get('content.someProperty');
```

and moreover, if `myController` is an `ObjectController` instance, then as a proxy, you can also write:

```
App.myController.get('someProperty');
```